# I have a Facebook page already, but I need an App ID to display my Gallery on my webpage with jQuery and FQL

Tags: jquery, facebook, gallery, facebook-fql

I'm interested in showing my Facebook gallery using FQL and jQuery on my webpage. I found something on this here:
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html

Here is the Facebook page that houses the photos:
http://www.facebook.com/KukuiCheltenham

However, I do not know how to generate an App ID and App Secret for this existing page (of which I am an admin).

Any thoughts on how to display the images from this pagebook page on my website (which is the official venue website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an application and prompt your own account for offline_access extended permissions and use that token to get the details needed from your page.  You can test this with the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=KukuiCheltenham/photos) and navigating to /KukuiCheltenham/photos.  If you tell the Graph Explorer you want offline_access you could even use that token.

Comment: For everyone's information, I believe that this approach is now depreciated since offline_access no longer exists in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, app ID and app secret are the identity for facebook application (either a canvas app or a fb connected website).  You cannot get appID / secret for a facebook page.